# Visual Studio Setup Project Remove install for all users

Tags: visual-studio

I am creating a setup project and want to remove the option to install for "everyone" or "just me" and have it default to just me.

Comment: Not enough reputation to answer my own question........

I figured it out.

View->Editor->User Interface. Click on Installation folder. In the properties window there is a key InstallAllUsersVisible. Set it to false

Comment: I want the inverse. Never allow 'just me' and require 'all users'. (administrator installing the product for everyone who logs into the machine).. is that possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> View->Editor->User Interface. Click on Installation folder. In the properties window there is a key InstallAllUsersVisible. Set it to false –

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to show the option at all in the screen. You can do the above said one "View->Editor->User Interface." in the properties window, Set the InstallAllUsersVisible. Set it to false.

If you wish not to show the details, then: click on the setup project, select "F4" button to open the setup project properties. In the properties list "InstallAllUser" properties to be set to false. This will make the option invisible.